# unexpected element error while unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I should unmarshall simple xml as belo but getting error as

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://example.com/service/response/v1", local:"WebResponse"). Expected elements are <{http://example.com/service/request/v1}WebResponse>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:603)

I tried the solutions in this site but could not solve pls help.
```

This is the xml present in response.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <WebResponse xmlns="http://example.com/service/response/v1">
- <Status>
  <StatusCode>0</StatusCode> 
  <Description>Transaction was successful</Description> 
  </Status>
  </WebResponse>
```

Below is my code :

**WebResponse class:**

The webresponse class for storing the retrieved xml

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="WebResponse")
public class WebResponse {

    private long statusCode;
    private String description;
    @XmlElement(name= "StatusCode")
    public long getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
    public void setStatusCode(long statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    @XmlElement(name= "Description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

**WebResponseMain class:**

Tester class

```
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

import java.io.FileReader;
import com.example.WebResponse;


public class WebResponseMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(WebResponse.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        WebResponse WR = (WebResponse) um.unmarshal(new FileReader("c:/tem/Response.XML"));
        System.out.println("StatusCode: " + WR.getStatusCode() + " Description "
                 +WR.getDescription());

    }

}
```

**package-info.java:**

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://example.com/service/request/v1",elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)



package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

i used the solutions present in this site but could not solve please help

Comment: i overlooked small thing Thanks Blaise this solved my exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part 1**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://example.com/service/response/v1", local:"WebResponse"). Expected elements are <{http://example.com/service/request/v1}WebResponse>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:603)
```

The problem is the namespaces specified in the XML (`response/v1` and `request/v1`).

```
<WebResponse xmlns="http://example.com/service/response/v1">
```

and `package-info` are different

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://example.com/service/request/v1", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example;
```

---

**Part 2**

Your current object model and mappings do not match the XML content.  One way to solve this would be to introduce a `Status` class [as answered by Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14520083/383861).

**Status**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Status {

    private long statusCode;
    private String description;

    @XmlElement(name = "StatusCode")
    public long getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(long statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

**WebResponse**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "WebResponse")
public class WebResponse {

    private Status status;

    @XmlElement(name="Status")
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

Comment: but i am not able to retrieve the value after unmarshalling it prints statuscode:0 and description:null pls help

Comment: That is what part 2 of my answer and the answer given by @Ash was about.  I have updated my answer with it would like like in code.

Comment: +1, this is much better than my answer Blaise! @user2010562, I think you should change this to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `Status` class, and put it between `WebResponse` and the fields.

I think that, since your XML elements go WebResponse -> Status -> StatusCode/Description, your `WebResponse` class should have only one field: a "status" of type `Status`. Class `Status` should then have the `StatusCode` and `Description` fields.

Edit: Also, I thought the @XmlElement annotations go on the fields, not the methods, but it's been a while since I've done it...

Comment: +1 for introducing a `Status` class this isn't what is causing the exception but will be needed to correctly unmarshal the data.  By default the annotations go on the methods, you can set them on the fields if your specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html