# Unmarshalling unexpected element error

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb2

I have a very similar problem to this topic [unexpected element error while unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519902/unexpected-element-error-while-unmarshalling), but still I am not able to solve the exception. As the namespace in XML and package-info is exactly the same... or is it because of the xsd file ?

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.example.org/Uni", local:"Uni"). Expected elements are <{http://www.example.org/Uni}uni>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:Uni xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Uni" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/Uni Uni.xsd ">
  <tns:Semester>
    <tns:nr>1</tns:nr>
    <tns:datum>01.02.2012</tns:datum>
  </tns:Semester>
   <tns:Semester>
    <tns:nr>2</tns:nr>
    <tns:datum>01.02.2012</tns:datum>
  </tns:Semester>
</tns:Uni>
```

XSD

```
<complexType name="Uni">
    <choice>
        <element name="Semester" type="tns:Semester" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
    </choice>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Semester">
    <sequence>
        <element name="nr" type="int"></element>
        <element name="datum" type="string"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

package-info

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://www.example.org/Uni", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package parserTest;
```

Uni.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Uni
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Semester")
    protected List<Semester>    semester;

    public List<Semester> getSemester()
    {
        if (this.semester == null)
        {
            this.semester = new ArrayList<Semester>();
        }
        return this.semester;
    }

}
```

Unmarshalling

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException
{
    ObjectFactory factoryForElementObjects = new ObjectFactory();
    List<Semester> semesterL = new ArrayList<Semester>();

    Uni uni = new Uni();
    uni.semester = semesterL;

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Uni.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Uni un = (Uni) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("src/main/resources/Uni.xml"));
    List<Semester> semesterA = un.semester;
    System.out.println(semesterA.get(0).nr);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that unmarshaller is expecting element `uni`, but it finds `Uni`.

Setting the XML element name for the Uni class should do the trick:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Uni")
public class Uni
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Semester")
    protected List<Semester>    semester;

    public List<Semester> getSemester()
    {
        if (this.semester == null)
        {
            this.semester = new ArrayList<Semester>();
        }
        return this.semester;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx.. I'll tag it as answered... just why is it expecting uni, I just used capital letters as I can see so far ... or because of the object uni ?

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert in JAXB, but I think it will always "prefer" creating XML elements with lower case. Found the answer marshalling an `Uni` object.

Comment: Personally, I use JAXB to marshall and unmarshall objects on the same application. Don't even use schemas. As I said, I'm no JAXB expert. But you can create Java classes given a schema with the Binding Compiler (xjc). You can also validate a XML given a schema (through JAXB in your application). If it sounds interesting, take a look: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html and http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/